# iOS app crashed in objc_moveWeak when _CFXNotificationRegisterObserver

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsnotifications

we found some crashes that quit hard to find the root cause, crash report as below:

---

```
OS Version:      iOS 16.3.1 (20D67)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_NO_ACCESS at 0x0000000000000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001aa885f70 objc_moveWeak + 204
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b1790830 _CFXNotificationRegistrarAddObserver + 396
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b178a95c CFXNotificationRegistrarAdd + 580
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b17a1b1c _CFXNotificationRegisterObserver + 248
4   MyApp                           0x00000001019600c0 -[XLogic _initNotification] 
.......


Thread 0 crashed with ARM-64 Thread State:
  cpsr: 0x0000000080001000     fp: 0x000000016ee5ed90     lr: 0xaf2f8001aa885f70     pc: 0x00000001aa885f70 
    sp: 0x000000016ee5ed50     x0: 0x00000002806e00e0     x1: 0x0000000000000008    x10: 0x0000000000000000 
   x11: 0x0000000000005037    x12: 0x0000000000005037    x13: 0x0000000000000028    x14: 0xfffffffd7f91ff20 
   x15: 0x00000001055e45c5    x16: 0x00000001aa885ea4    x17: 0x0000000208eeb9f8    x18: 0x0000000000000000 
   x19: 0x00000003d6b78008     x2: 0x0000000000000008    x20: 0x0000000000000008    x21: 0x00000002806e00e0 
   x22: 0x0000000207a850c0    x23: 0x0000000207a850e0    x24: 0x0000000207a8cce0    x25: 0x0000000000000006 
   x26: 0x00000003d6b78000    x27: 0x0000000000000000    x28: 0x000000035151c9b0    x29: 0x000000016ee5ed90 
    x3: 0x0000000000000002     x4: 0x0000000003000001     x5: 0x0000000000000003     x6: 0x0000000000000000 
    x7: 0x0000000000000000     x8: 0x00000003330fc898     x9: 0xfffffffffffffff8
```

---

this kind of crash happens during init in different views or classes, the app has a bad memory leakage in this version, after hours of usage in background and foreground without killing the app , crash may occurs.

Do you find any clue? hope for your reply.

we tried to reproduce this crash, but failed. we think this crash may caused by out of memory, but have no proof.

Comment: Hi, did you find what was the issue?